# How to create Listview inside CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to create a layout with:
toolbar on top
tablayout with 3 tabs
two of the tabs show a list
one of the tab shows a grid

On scrolling the list/grid the toolbar should collapse and the tablayout should go on top. I have this worked out but I am working with a dummy list of the type:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
....>
    <LinearLayout
    ...
    />
    ...
    .... copied 10 times
</NestedScrollView>
```

I now want to use a real list, like a listview and a gridview. What do I use? Is it okay to use a listview inside a NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `RecyclerView` instead of `Listview`. Take a look at this android developer blog post about the Design Support Library [[LINK]](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Also never use a `ListView` / `GridView` / `RecyclerView` in `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`. [[LINK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Answer (score 2):

try it in listview:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```